# OpenCV color-value of a pixel by using mat.get() returns sometimes null

Tags: java, android, opencv

I try to get the RGB Values of a pixel using mat.get(inx, int y) on Android and OpenCV 2.4.4.

```
Mat img = Utils.loadResource(getBaseContext(), R.drawable.ex3);
double[] tmp = img.get(100, 100);
if(printLog) Log.v(tag, "Color: "+ tmp[0] +","+ tmp[1] +","+ tmp[2] +"");
```

Normaly I got the tmp-Array returned. But at some pixels, i got returned "null". (That points are in range of the picture!)

So why I get at some coordinates a array and on some others "null" and how to fix that?

Comment: There is no such method as `get` in `cv::Mat`. What is the type of `img`?

Comment: The type of img is Mat

Comment: hier is the doc of that get in mat: http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#get%28int,%20int%29

Comment: Has your image 3 channels? Which is the output of `System.out.println(img.channels())`?

Comment: So looks like everything is correct. Have you tried to write Mat to the image file and see if its representation is ok? In other words if there is no distortion in pixels... also try to `img.release();` after each use. I've already had the similar problem because of memory.

Comment: How do you now how much channels your image has?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At OpenCV by getting pixelinformations with Mat.get(row, col) the meaning of X and Y is changed: Use Y for the row and X for the col.

```
Mat.get(Y, X);
```

So in my case I was out of range but openCV did not return a Exception. It returns "null"

Comment: can it throws an Exception?

Answer (score 0):

I'd first check how many channels your `Mat` got with `Mat::channels()` and then access to them through:

> double[] tmp = img.at(100,100);

Answer (score -1):

To access each pixel separately you can do this if you are using https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv

```
      IplImage image = cvLoadImage("path/to/image/get.jpg");

      public void colorProcess(IplImage image){
        CvMat result = CvMat.create(image.width(),image.height(), CV_32F);
        CvMat ff =image.asCvMat(); 

        for(int a=0;a<result.cols();a++){
             for(int b=0;b<result.rows();b++){

                CvScalar rgb = cvGet2D(ff, a, b);
                System.out.println("blue "+rgb.getVal(0)+"green "+rgb.getVal(1)+"red    "+rgb.getVal(2));

              }
        }

      }
```